# IsPostBack is always false

Tags: vb.net, webforms

I have seen many questions that sound the same as mine, but all of them are about different scenarios, and I have not found any solution for my issue. After I click an asp:LinkButton lnkInit on a modal dialog, the IsPostback is always false, and the event handler is never called. Here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Pricebook/My.Master" CodeBehind="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="MyWebCore.Pricebook._default"
```

...

```
<div id="modal_customer" class="modal fade modal_customer" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Select Your Customer" aria-describedby="Select a customer to generate a customizable pricelist" runat="server">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2 class="modal-title">Select Your Customer</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCustomer" AssociatedControlID="ddCustomer" Text="Customer Selection" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:DropDownList id="ddCustomer" CssClass="form-control customer_list" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkInit" CssClass="btn btn-primary" text="Begin" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code-behind:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
....
    If Not IsPostBack Then
' ... Always gets here :(
    End If
```

...

```
Sub lnkInit_Click(ByVal objSender As Object, ByVal objArgs As EventArgs) Handles lnkInit.Click
'...  Never gets here
End Sub
```

An additional strange fact is that this way the application behaves when I run it in my Visual Studio, and when I run it as a QA web application on IIS of our Azure VM, but when I run it as a Production application on the same IIS, it works normal. I have no idea how I could debug this.

Comment: My memory of webforms is foggy but I don't see you attach an event handler and your page directive defines `AutoEventWireUp` as false. I think you are redirecting instead of posting.

Comment: Isn't it what "Handles lnkInit.Click" does as an alternative?

Comment: @DavidShochet not if `AutoEventWireUp` is false to my recollection.

Comment: [Looks like I'm wrong](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/02/17/inside-autoeventwireup.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when I added PostBackUrl to the same page:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkInit" CssClass="btn btn-primary" text="Begin" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/pricebook/default.aspx"></asp:LinkButton>
```